# svn copy failing when trying to create branches

Tags: svn, copy

I created a repository in my local machine:

```
svnadmin create /home/me/Desktop/svn_test/trunk
```

Then import myDir directory to the repository.

```
svn import myDir/ file://home/me/Desktop/svn_test/trunk
```

So far svn checkout, commit, update works fine.

Now, I want to create branch from the repository, so I followed the tutorial and executed:

( svn copy source destination )

```
svn copy file:///home/me/Desktop/svn_test/trunk file:///home/me/Desktop/svn_test/branches
```

Then I got:

```
svn: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL
svn: Unable to open repository 'file:///home/me/Desktop/svn_test'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

After carefully examine the sample command, I found out there are backslashes like below, what are those? (and still get error)

```
svn copy file:///home/me/Desktop/svn_test/trunk \ file:///home/me/Desktop/svn_test/branches \ -m "test"
svn: Cannot mix repository and working copy sources
```

Comment: Probably just a typo in your question, but you seem to be missing a forward-slash in your import line.

Comment: Does that cause svn copy to fail? import command did not throw any error and other commands such as checkout, commit etc are working fine. I'm having issue with svn copy command. I've edited to get more detail, but not really sure what that backslashes are doing here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You didn't create a repository in svn_test

You created it in svn_test/trunk

You want

```
$ svnadmin create /home/me/Desktop/svn_test
```

instead.

The way you did it, svn_test/trunk is the repo, so subversion can't do anthying about svn_test/branches -- since that is not a repository path.

EDIT (for clarity):

What you want to do is something like this:

```
$ mkdir /path/to/repo               # NO /trunk!
$ svnadmin create /path/to/repo     # NO /trunk!
$ svn import -m "initial import" . file:///path/to/repo/trunk    #import into a directory called "/trunk" that lives in the repository
$ svn co file:///path/to/repo/trunk myproject
$ cd myproject
$ # do some stuff to your working copy...
$ svn commit -m "I made some changes"
$ # decide you want to make a branch...
$ svn copy -m "branching for some reason" file:///path/to/repo/trunk file:///path/to/repo/branches/some-branch
```

Note that there is no mention of "trunk" until the `svn import` happens.

Comment: I've updated the question, sorry it was typo so I actually created repository in /home/me/Desktop/svn_test/trunk

Comment: Ignore the backslashes you saw -- they're for making multi-line commands in shell.  Your problem is still that "trunk" is not supposed to be the repository, just a directory that is *in* the repository.  Editing my answer to give a proper demo.

Comment: Great! it's working now, thank you! I confused the use of trunk between my project dir and repository.