# Call SVN console client from C#

Tags: c#, .net, svn, console-application

any ideas how to create a branch from a trunk url in a c# console app.

im trying to create a branching tool, that will create all new branches. for the life of me i have tried almost everything. Sharpsvn has given me no luck.

```
string command = "cp https://svn:8443/svn/blah/trunk \\ https://svn:8443/svn/blah/branches/newBranch \\";
Process svnBranchProcess = new Process();
svnBranchProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "Svn.exe";
svnBranchProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = command;
svnBranchProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
svnBranchProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
svnBranchProcess.Start();

string output = svnBranchProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
svnBranchProcess.WaitForExit();

Console.WriteLine("Output:");
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

This is the error that i get

> svn : Cannot mix repository and working copy sources

Basically i want to be able to create a branch off trunk and then update some externals. why is this such a mission?

thanks for any help :)

Comment: Does your command work from regular console?

Comment: Get rid of the double backslashes from your `cp` command.

Comment: What was the problem with SharpSVN?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517275/svn-copy-failing-when-tring-to-create-branches